# Can't connect to mysql in golang with a user with locahost-only access (other than root)

Tags: mysql, go, connection

I created a user 'gou' for all my golang projects.

```
create user 'gou'@'localhost' identified by 'gop';
grant select, insert, update, delete, create, drop, alter on gdb.* to 'gou'@'localhost';
```

This is the code in go:

```
...
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
...


db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "gou:gop@tcp(localhost:3306)/gdb?parseTime=true")
```

When I run the code I am getting (IP omitted):

`Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'gou'@'my.very.own.ip' (using password: YES) exit status 1`

Note: I can actually run the code:

- using root user, but I don't want to use root
- useing user 'gou'@'%', but I only want to access from localhost

Comment: mysql interprets `localhost` as a unix socket for the purposes of create user.  Try adding my.very.own.ip in the user instead of localhost - or 127.0.0.1 if that isn't my.very.own.ip

Answer (score 0):

set password for user gou and access your database using

cfg := mysql.Config{
User: gou,
Passwd: password,
Net: "tcp",
Addr: "127.0.0.1:3306",
DBName: "dbname", }

db, err = sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a password for your mysql user, then:

```golang
//Or maybe this line works good too:
const (
    host = "localhost"
    port = 8080

    dbUser = "myUser"
    dbPass = "myPassOfMysql"
    dbHost = "localhost"
    dbPort = "3306"
    dbName = "MyDBName"
)
mysqlURI := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, dbPort, dbName)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mysqlURI)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```